# mysql 5.7 unable to log in after installation

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql as part of a LAMP setup, using the command:

```
$ sudo apt install lamp-server^
```

I then ran mysql_secure_installation and provided a root password.

When I try to connect to mysql, whatever I try, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get into mysql?  Many thanks.

Peter

Comment: Close and open the terminal and try again!

Comment: Tried that.  Even shutdown and restarted.  No difference.

Comment: please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: Just tried the first suggestion.  No luck:

Comment: And the second, and what error messages are you getting?

Comment: The first suggestion should have -p in my opinion. So try `mysql -u root -p`.

Comment: Just realised I can now get in by doing
    mysql -u root
but NOT when I do mysql -u root -p

I was adding the -p option when I reported failure earlier

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to George Udosen for pointing me to the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

I used the first solution since this is a local database and doesn't have to be secure.

However, I did discover that I hadn't set a password even though I thought I had, via mysql_secure_installation.  So I could only get into mysql using

```
mysql -u root
```

and not by using:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Having got that far, I installed mysql Workbench and set a password there.  It now all works as it should.

Thanks to all, especially George.

Another one down.